# AWS PHP SDK Version 2 S3 filename encoding issue

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We've been using the AWS SDK with pretty good results for uploading/grabbing files, but we ran into a snag.

There is a file stored in S3 that looks like it was urlescaped.
`"/mefile/412501_413000/412604_-12%20C008%20Fil%20R[1].doc.gpg"`

So far the SDK has managed to handle every mangled filename we've thrown at it.  But when I try a "doesObjectExist" I also get a failure for that file.

`$s3->doesObjectExist("mabucket","/mefile/412501_413000/412604_-12%20C008%20Fil%20R[1].doc.gpg")`

will always fail.  I've tried uploading that file from a local storage and that fails as well.  I get a funky exceptions:
"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

Is there any trick I need to encode the filename with before using the "doesObjectExist".  It seems to handle all sorts of bad filenames already (spaces/utf-8 chars/& etc), so I'm confused why this doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**
Upgrading to the latest AWS SDK for PHP 2.2.1.  Was running on version 2.1.0 which apparently had several bugs.  If you are on Ubuntu 10.04, this is a bit rough.  (See comments about PHP version upgrades here: http://www.zalexblog.com/2011/01/07/installing-php-5-3-3-on-ubuntu-10-04/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with html_entity_decode ?

```
$s3->doesObjectExist("mabucket",html_entity_decode("/mefile/412501_413000/412604_-12%20C008%20Fil%20R[1].doc.gpg"))
```

Comment: Sorry no.  I've tried every decode in php: html_entity_decode,rawurldecode,urldecode .

Comment: Could it be the bucket location ?

https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/issues/28#issuecomment-5723770

Comment: $config = array(
    'key'    => 'the-aws-key',
    'secret' => 'the-aws-secret',
    'region' => Region::US_EAST_1
);

It was in the default to begin with, but I gave it a shot.  Still not working.

Comment: @CarlosCastillo your comment was the solution to my problem here, if you'd like to answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805601/amazon-s3-sdk-php-doesobjectexist-problems

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest AWS SDK for PHP 2.2.1. Was running on version 2.1.0 which apparently had several bugs. If you are on Ubuntu 10.04, this is a bit rough. (See comments about PHP version upgrades here: http://www.zalexblog.com/2011/01/07/installing-php-5-3-3-on-ubuntu-10-04/)

Answer (score 0):

urldecode() of the key/filename worked for me