# Amazon S3 SDK PHP doesObjectExist() problems

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've re-written this question to make it clearer, since I've updated it.

I'm having trouble with the Amazon AWS S3 PHP SDK. I'm just trying to check if a file exists.
Using this PHP script:

```
<?php
    require_once("../../../configs/config.".get_current_user().".php");
    require INCLUDES_PATH . 'libraries/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;

    $client = S3Client::factory(array(
          'key' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
          'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY
      ));

    $key = 'profile/avatar/80745d03-c295-4205-bd82-58161f2fd2d1-320.jpg';
    $result = $client->doesObjectExist( AWS_S3_BUCKET, $key );

    var_dump(AWS_S3_BUCKET);
    var_dump($key);
    var_dump($result);

?>
```

This is the output:

```
string(19) "stage.socialite.app"
string(59) "profile/avatar/80745d03-c295-4205-bd82-58161f2fd2d1-320.jpg"
bool(false)
```

I know the file exists, it's here:

http://stage.socialite.app.s3.amazonaws.com/profile/avatar/80745d03-c295-4205-bd82-58161f2fd2d1-320.jpg

This is the IAM policy for the user, whose Key ID and Secret Key I'm using:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::stage.socialite.app/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::stage.socialite.app"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've just created a new Key/Secret pair and added them to my config - what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on another SO post, in a comment from [Carlos Castillo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1897337/carlos-castillo):

[AWS PHP SDK Version 2 S3 filename encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558289/aws-php-sdk-version-2-s3-filename-encoding-issue)

He pointed me in the direction of a [Github Issue](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/issues/28#issuecomment-5723770) that suggested setting the region when initializing the S3 client, this is because I'm using an S3 instance in Ireland for my dev server, not the default US servers.

So this is the solution:

```
$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    'region' => AWS_S3_REGION
));
```

Where `AWS_S3_REGION` is a constant set in my config file, like the Key and Secret.

Credit goes to [neilscastle](https://github.com/nielscastle), Carlos and Stack Overflow for it's excellent SEO

Comment: Ah, the bucket location being the problem makes sense.

Comment: As a side note you can pass `@region` into the opts for the call to `doesObjectExist` itself, which often makes the most sense if you have some sort of reverse lookup function like we do for processing s3 files inter-regionally ie `getRegionFromBucket()`.

Answer (score 8):

If `var_dump()` says `bool(false)` or `bool(true)`, then it is correctly returning a boolean value. `print_r()` does not include detailed type information and returns an empty string for `false` and `null` values.

So does the object actually exist? Things to check on:

- S3 keys do not have a leading slashes. According to your code and output above, I suspect this is the problem.
- Make sure you are providing the actual S3 bucket name and not the CloudFront distribution name.
- `doesObjectExist()` returns false if the user does not have read permissions for that object.

Comment: I added the leading slash as it wasn't working without, I'll remove it and update the top question, and double check that's not the problem - I suspect then it might be the permissions problem.

Comment: For me the problem was the leading slash, removing it solved it!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to correct bucket location and read permissions:

If using server-side encryption you need to provide the SSE options with `doesObjectExist`.

```
$s3Client->doesObjectExist($bucket, $key, array(
    'SSECustomerAlgorithm' => 'AES256',
    'SSECustomerKey'       => $encryptionKey,
    'SSECustomerKeyMD5'    => md5($encryptionKey, true)
));
```

Missing or incorrect SSE options will yield `false` return from  `doesObjectExist`.