# How to test if S3 object does not exist AWS PHP SDK (Version 3)?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have written an integration for the [AWS SDK in PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-examples.html) to send the keys for files on an S3 bucket and retrieve a pre-signed url, which more or less follows [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html). This worked perfectly except I need to now check if the file exists on s3 and return empty string if it does not.

I am doing this with my code below:

```
<?php

public function getUrl($key, $region, $version, $fileBucket): string
{
    $this->s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'region' => $region,
        'version' => $version,
    ]);

    if ($this->s3Client->doesObjectExist($fileBucket, $key) === false) {
       return '';
    }

    $cmd = $this->s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => $fileBucket,
        'Key' => $key
    ]);

    $request = $this->s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, $preSignedExpiration);

    $preSignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();

    return $preSignedUrl ?? '';
}
```

My code returned the presigned urls perfectly until I added the if statement checking the method doesObjectExist(). doesObjectExist() returns false for all of my objects on S3, and not just the ones with a $key that does not exist in the S3 bucket. So that rules out the S3 keys, buckets or api keys being invalid, which has been the [answer I have come across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805601/amazon-s3-sdk-php-doesobjectexist-problems#answer-22822050) researching this issue primarily.

Also if you happen to know a better way to do this using what is returned in $cmd or $request, without having to call doesObjectExist() (if it is possible) that would simplify my code a bit.

Edit:

The policy for the IAM user I am accessing the AWS S3 API through looks like this:

```
{    
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-dev-us-east-1-111111111111",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-dev-us-east-1-111111111111/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the s3 Bucket policy looks like:

```
       {
        "Sid": "dev-web-app-get-policy",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::2222222222:role/example-dev-us-east-1-111111111111"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::example-dev-us-east-1-111111111111",
            "arn:aws:s3:::example-dev-us-east-1-111111111111/*"
        ]
    }
```

So it would seem that I should be able to access the needed resources. I listed fake bucket names, for security. But I have checked that those mathc s3 in the console.

When have tried calling the the api for the HeadObject like this:

```
$this->s3Client->headObject([
    'Bucket' => $fileBucket,
    'Key' => $key
]);
```

And I get the following message:

```
"Error executing \"HeadObject\" on \"https://example-dev-us-east-1-111111111111/54bf7350-a819-41dd-9da3-3710eb8b095a-Screenshot_2021-03-09_20-15-12.png\"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `HEAD https://example-dev-us-east-1-111111111111/54bf7350-a819-41dd-9da3-3710eb8b095a-Screenshot_2021-03-09_20-15-12.png` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response  (client): 403 Forbidden (Request-ID: XR6W77BB817407K2) - ",
"url": "/files.json"
```

Not sure if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `s3:GetObject` permission to invoke the [HeadObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html) API, which is what the PHP SDK invokes when your code calls `doesObjectExist()`.

> If the object you request does not exist, the error Amazon S3 returns
> depends on whether you also have the s3:ListBucket permission.
>
> - If you have the s3:ListBucket permission on the bucket, Amazon S3
>   returns an HTTP status code 404 ("no such key") error.
> - If you don’t
>   have the s3:ListBucket permission, Amazon S3 returns an HTTP status
>   code 403 ("access denied") error.

So, you probably have s3:ListBucket but not s3:GetObject.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my question with the bucket policies, which seems to contain the permissions your referring to. I also tested against a temporary user with no api restrictions (AwsS3FullAccess) and I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: The resources should be S3 ARNs, not simply prefixed with the bucket names. Are they correct? Have you attempted HeadObject or GetObject using the awscli with these credentials? FYI that’s not a bucket policy; it’s an IAM policy.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the real bucket names, since they are specific to the architecture of the app. I should have explained that better. Yes the bucket names in the IAM policy match my S3 buckets, Like I mentioned in the question the call to GetObject in my code works (minus keys for non existent objects being filtered) if I pull out the 3 lines that return '' if doesObjectExist() returned false. I have updated the question with an attempt to get the HeadObject and am getting a 403 error, that posted the question. Thanks!

Comment: FYI you can create a pre-signed URL for any object, including one that doesn’t exist and one that you don’t have permission to access. The failure will come later when you attempt to access the actual object, so don’t read anything into the fact that you were able to create a pre-signed URL (it will pretty much always succeed, regardless of permissions).

Comment: Per my answer, if you get 404 when calling HeadObject then you have S3:ListBucket but not S3:GetObject. If you get 403 then you don’t have S3:ListBucket.

Comment: Both s3:ListBucket and s3:GetObject are listed in the IAM policy for the user I am using for the API, in the edit for my question. Are you saying that I need to grant these permissions somewhere else?

Comment: I would check that the S3 bucket does not have a conflicting policy. And I would test the same credentials with the awscli for both HeadObject and GetObject.

Comment: I have added the s3 bucket policy as well.

Comment: You originally mentioned that you’re using an IAM user but now you’re showing a bucket policy that appears to imply cross-account role permissions. Is this cross-account? What is making the S3 API requests - is it an IAM user in a different account or an IAM role in a different account?

Comment: I think I have it working now. Not sure what was going on entirely but I think I may have had another user's api credentials cached in my local environment or something and the policies needed to be tweaked a little. Thanks for the help!